# Join between tables in two different databases?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

In MySQL, I have two different databases -- let's call them **A** and **B**.

Is it possible to perform a join between a table that is in database **A**, to a table that is in database **B**?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Yes, assuming the account has appropriate permissions you can use:

```
SELECT <...>
FROM A.table1 t1 JOIN B.table2 t2 ON t2.column2 = t1.column1;
```

You just need to prefix the table reference with the name of the database it resides in.

Comment: What about two databases from different servers? (for example, one db on a cloud service server, and on db on your own server)

Comment: Is it possible to join to different DB's, DB1 = mysql & DB2 = PostgreSQL) . Both have few common tables.

Comment: @YuvalA.@boatcoder i don't think yuval is asking about performance.  simply asking about how to do a cross-server join.  would be quite difficult since you need to ask the client to make two connections.

Comment: make sure that the database name is NOT inside the same backticks as the table name otherwise you will get `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'currentdb.otherdb.tablename' doesn't exist`

Comment: Thanks. it also worked with me without alias names `FROM A.table1  JOIN B.table2  ON B.table2 .column2 =  A.table1.column1`

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT <...> 
FROM A.tableA JOIN B.tableB
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM A.tableA JOIN B.tableB
```

or

```
SELECT *
  FROM A.tableA JOIN B.tableB
  ON A.tableA.id = B.tableB.a_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT <...>
FROM A.table1 t1 JOIN B.table2 t2 ON t2.column2 = t1.column1;
```

Just make sure that in the SELECT line you specify which table columns you are using, either by full reference, or by alias. Any of the following will work:

```
SELECT *
SELECT t1.*,t2.column2
SELECT A.table1.column1, t2.*
etc.
```