# Is it possible to implement JOIN queries with 2 Mysql Databases?

Tags: mysql, join, cross-join

I am working in Moodle and CodeIgnitor together in one project; a few of my tables are in moodle db and other tables are in another database.

Is it possible to implement JOIN queries with two Mysql Databases to fetch the data we require?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL -- join between tables in 2 different databases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698378/mysql-join-between-tables-in-2-different-databases)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**YES**

- both database are using the same daemon (meaning same port, same server)
- user account has **enough ACL** to access both databases
- if you are able to construct query yourself

**NO**

- certain framework / data modelling will restrict you do so (that's mean the **CODE** teaching you how to do the SQL, and you cannot against their rules (unless putting your hack)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

If DB are on the same server, you can use

```
select a.col from db1.table1 a, db2.table2 b where a.col = b.col
```

Obviously you would put your join condition in here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Instead of using the "default" (currently selected) database, [you can explicitly specify the database name](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) when you reference your tables and fields:

> You can refer to a table within the default database as tbl_name, or
>   as db_name.tbl_name to specify a database explicitly. You can refer to
>   a column as col_name, tbl_name.col_name, or db_name.tbl_name.col_name

However, I don't recommend this. If data are related between tables then they are supposed to be in the *same* database. That's what would make sense!

Comment: I don't agree with your last statement.
It is perfectly reasonable to have two systems which are discreet in their operation, however for example for Management Information purposes simmilar data needs to be assimilated for reporting, for example financial transactions. It wouldn't be appropriate for both systems to use the same DB.

Comment: Tables represent data relationships. Databases are groupings of these relations, each of which can be cross-examined to produce intersections and other nice stuff. The database is the singular, all-encompassing body of potentially-related data. One system, one database. I _can_ see, however, that it might be useful when accumulating data from multiple systems.

Comment: I wasn't disputing the definition of a DB.

Comment: Please remove your downvote. We don't downvote for disagreeing with opinions here, like we do on Meta. We downvote for "significantly wrong or irrelevant or misleading or offers really bad advice" and -- given my factual answer and quote from the documentation -- I can't see how that applies here.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2282/discussion-between-diagonalbatman-and-tomalak-geretkal)