# MySQL add current db as prefix automatically

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have two databases db1 and db2, and I have full privileges to access them.
But when I issue the following sql:

```
SELECT * FROM `db1.tbl1` AS t1 JOIN `db2.tbl2` AS t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
```

I get this error:

```
Table `db1.db1.tbl1` doesn't exist.
```

`db1.tbl1` does exist. It seems mysql automatically add database name as prefix. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You should backtick quote the database name and table name separately:**

```
SELECT * FROM `db1`.`tbl1` AS t1 JOIN `db2`.`tbl2` AS t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
```

Or just without backticks if there is no reserve name.

```
SELECT * FROM db1.tbl1 AS t1 JOIN db2.tbl2 AS t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM `db1`.`tbl1` AS t1 JOIN `db2`.`tbl2` AS t2 ON t1.id=t2.id;
```

You need to add the ` till with the both table name and database name.

Comment: I don't think so. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698378/mysql-join-between-tables-in-2-different-databases

Comment: You mean I can't join two tables from two different databases? I don't think so...