# MySQL table with view from deferent database table?

Tags: mysql

I need to create a MySQL table with view from deferent database table. Is it possible? If yes how?

`Data1.Table1` has 6 columns. I need to use this 6 columns and about 20 new other field with `Data2.Table2`. Is it possible? If yes how?

Comment: Not sure about what you asking. Would this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698378/mysql-join-between-tables-in-2-different-databases

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible if you're database is in one server, give some ALIASES to the two tables. Please see example below:

```
SELECT tbl1.col1,tbl1.col2,tbl1.col3,tbl1.col4,tbl1.col5,tbl1.col6, tbl2.*
FROM DB1.TBL1 AS tbl1
INNER JOIN DB2.TBL3 AS tbl2 ON tbl1.ID = tbl2.ID;
```