# Join two tables belong to two database in Elixir Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

In Elixir, with Ecto, is it possible to join two different tables (in the same host) belonging to different two databases.

There are two databases called `cloud` and `cloud_usage` in this query

When I execute the query, which Repo should I use?

`Billing.CloudUsage.Repo.all(query)`

or

`Billing.Cloud.Repo.all(query)`

```
    query = from cucu in "cloud_usage.cloud_usage",
        inner_join: cv in "cloud.volumes", on: cucu.usage_id == cv.id,
          where: cucu.account_id == ^account_id,
          where: cucu.usage_id == 6,
          where: like(cucu.description, ^vol_description),
          where: cucu.start_date >= ^start_datetime,
          where: cucu.start_date <= ^end_datetime,
       group_by: cucu.usage_id,
       group_by: cucu.zone_id,
         select: {cucu.usage_id, cucu.zone_id, cucu.size, sum(cucu.raw_usage)}
　　　result  = Billing.CloudUsage.Repo.all(query)
```

When I call the function I got the error

```
** (Mariaex.Error) (1146): Table 'cloud_usage.cloud_usage.cloud_usage' doesn't exist
```

I know why this happened. But If I use `Billing.Cloud.Repo.all(query)` , I think I can hardly retrieve the data in `cloud_usage.cloud_usage` table. Vice versa

Reference:

[MySQL -- join between tables in 2 different databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698378/mysql-join-between-tables-in-2-different-databases)

Comment: Please include the specific error you are getting.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Please include the error you are getting and the Ecto version. Also notice that you have a typo in your query. It should be `, on: cucu` and not `, on cucu`.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots, instead paste the code in your question and format it properly using the `{}` button in the editor. You should only post relevant parts of the code, not unnecessary comments. If you want to get good answers, you should make it as easy as possible for the readers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is perfect. This is a bug in Ecto. I have fixed it in master if you want to give it a try. :)

Comment: José, It worked!! Really appreciate your work! In order to try the master ecto, I need to change the  `mix.exs` file . `{:ecto, github: "elixir-lang/ecto"},`