# codeigniter - best way to get data from 2 tables in different database through foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, prepared-statement

I have 2 databases `db_1` and `db_2`.
`db_1` contains table `users` (contains `'uid','name'` columns)
`db_2` contains table `blog_posts` (contains `'pid','uid','post_title'` columns)
I want to extract 20 posts from `blog_posts` along with user's name corresponding to `uid` mentioned in `blog_posts`. I tried to use '`join`' with codeigniter prepared mysql statements, but it didn't work.
What is the best way to get this data. I don't want to get name one by one for each `uid` as it will create database connection many times i.e. 21 (1 for getting all posts and 20 to get each post user name) which slow down the speed. Is there any more effective method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have got an answer for the question. We can do the following. It will create only 2 database connections.

1. Get all the posts with `'pid','uid','post_title'` you want to show,
   say 20 in your case. Like, 
   `$post_data=
   array(
     0=>array(
       'pid'=>1,
       'uid'=>2,
       'post_title'=>'Hello there!'
     ),
     1=>array(
       'pid'=>2,
       'uid'=>5,
       'post_title'=>'What's up!'
     )
   );`
2. Now, get list of names from `users` corresponding to all `uid` you get in Step 1 in an array.

   `$user_map=
     array(
       '2'=>'John',
       '5'=>'Robert',
       '11'=>'David'
     );`
3. Now, you can print user's name who belongs to the post as follows:

   `foreach($post_data as $value) {
       echo $value['post_title']."-".$user_map[$value['uid']];
     }`

Comment: If the databases db_1 and db_2 are on the same MySQL server you can get this in one query. Please look at the answer at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5698396/393865).

Comment: But CodeIgniter creates database connection first before executing any query. So we can access only one database in 1 query.

Comment: If your MySQL user has access to both databases you can query both databases using prefixes like db_1.table_name, no matter which connection CodeIgniter is using.

Comment: If we are using codeigniter prepared statements, is it the right way to call different database table like this. I mean codeigniter have proper way to create connection with database like this, `$this->load->database('db_1', TRUE);`. But here we are overriding this.