# how to excute conjunctive query crossing two mysql databases with gorm?

Tags: mysql, database, go, go-gorm

code like:

```
addr:=fmt.Sprintf(`%v:%v@tcp(%v:%v)/(%v,%v)?charset=utf8`, dbuser, dbpassword, dbhost, dbport, dbdatabase)

DB, err = gorm.Open("mysql", addr)

sql := "select * from db1.user join db2.salary"
 
rows, err := DB.Raw(sql).Rows()
```

it seems the method gorm.Open() only accept one source parameter, and it run error "unknown table name 'db1.user'"

is there a correct way to init the DB to excute the sql or other way to solve the problem?

many thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/5698378/13860

Comment: no ,the problem is how to excute the sql with GORM

Comment: Can you note which version of the gorm package you are using?

So you want to connect to a single mysql instance which contains two databases, db1 and db2, and make a join between tables in these two. Is that right?

Comment: yes , and it's solved by setting dbdatabase="" to init the parameter addr. The version should do not matter

Answer (score 0):

sovled by setting dbdatabase="" , which it means giving null database name connecting to the mysql instance. And database name shoud be presented as prefix on table name in sql.